# How to re-plumb when trap next to stack?

Tags: plumbing

I am Finishing my laundry room and existing sink drain has a trap right next to stack, which I believe is wrong ( *see pic* ).

I'm wanting to replace the sink ( *to the left in the pic* ), but would prefer not to mess with the stack.  Is there any legitimate way to do this plumbing right/acceptable, without redoing the stack joint?

Could I...

1. Just leave the trap and add another trap immediately under the new sink?
2. cut into the trap on the right 45-bend and tie in there, maybe even immediately raise the run to the left above where the joint enters the stack?

   I'm a DIY who has done PVC plumbing but reading online, messing with the stack is probably beyond me.

Any other options?

Thanks for any insight!

[image]

Comment: Yes the jpg is now visible.

Comment: Yes your pics look good. Two traps on a single fixture leg is a no no. I am wondering why it's there; did the old existing sink have a trap under it?

Comment: no the sink to the left had no trap, just a straight run into the trap shown

Comment: I guess another option would be to put the sink above the current trap or really close to it, and just use that existing trap - is that acceptable?